# when should i use PTR with indirect operands ?

Tags: assembly, x86, masm, pointers

I'm little confused with the rules of using the "xxxx PTR" with indirect operand.
Can anybody make it clear ? 
Thanks

Comment: Are you talking about MASM? Because other assemblers have better syntax without "PTR" directive.

Comment: You should use it when the size of an operand otherwise would be ambiguous, as in `mov [eax],0`.

Comment: i'm talking about MASM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you refer to this mnemonic syntax (e.g. `objdump -Mintel`):

```
add DWORD PTR [eax],0x5
```

The point here is that `[eax]` is just a location in memory, but it doesn't carry *size* information. So we don't know whether to add 5 to a byte, a word, a dword or a qword. It would be clear if we used the annotated opcode names (`addb`, `addw`, `addl`, `addq`), but this particular dialect of assember chooses instead to annotate the memory operand. In this case, it says, "treat `eax` is a pointer to a dword".

By contrast, register operands need no such annotation, since the register name implies its size:

```
add  al,0x5    ; addb
add  ax,0x5    ; addw
add eax,0x5    ; addl
add rax,0x5    ; addq
```

Comment: when i write the following line: mov eax,OFFSET var1 (var1 is Byte), so i don't need the PTR while adding BYTE operand ?

Comment: @user704023: What is `var1`? An immedate value? The destination register determines the size (so dword for `eax`).

Comment: var1 is a name of a byte variable

Comment: @user704023: That will put the *address* of that variable into `eax`, I think, so that's in some sense the opposite of `PTR`.

Comment: @user704023: If you know C, think of `PTR` as `*` and `OFFSET` as `&`. Note how `*` requires you to know the type, while `&` always returns a pointer (which in x86 protected mode all have the same size).